# $this->request->getArgument('group'); not working outside the plugin for breadcrums

Tags: typo3, fluid

I building an TYPO3 extension, withs contains a frond-end plugin. In the fluid template I'm using the following link. This links contains the argument named "group" to send the value "3" to the page.

```
<f:link.action pageUid="1" pluginName="PluginAds" controller="Ads" arguments="{group: 3}">
```

In the controller "PluginAds" under "AdsController" it works ok to get the value with the following action:

```
$this->request->getArgument('group');
```

But I also want to use the argument "group" for generating the correct breadcrums link. But when I use the same code in a different controller I'm getting the error that the argument does not exists. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect with browser tools how does `f:link.action` constructs prefixes for params of your plugin, it's i.e.: `tx_extkey_pluginsname[myparam]`

Within the plugin's actions you can get `myparam` by
`$this->request->getArgument('myparam')`

anyway anywhere else you need to get it as normal `GET` array, so it will be something like:

```
$pluginsParams = GeneralUtility::_GET('tx_extkey_pluginsname');
$myParam = $pluginsParams['myparam'];
```

Other thing is that you should always check if:

```
$this->request->hasArgument('group')
```

Before trying using it, otherwise it can lead you to null pointer exception.